# Cleaner form validation code [React Redux Thunk]?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm building a web page that has a complex dynamic form (Lot of fields), I want to keep things cleaner and shorter for the sake of readability and maintenance. 
In this case, I felt like there should be a better way to handle complex form validation like this

For example, here are some of my codes,

```js
// reducer.js
// Let's create our initial employee state for our reducer

initialState = {
  id: null,
  name: '',
  gender: '',
  email: '',
  role: '',
  address: '',
  phoneNumber: '',
  experiences: [  // Array of experiences (Appendable)
    {
      id: null,
      description: '',
      error: null // Every item has it's own error value
    }
  ],
  errors: { // Error value for every single field
    name: null,
    gender: null,
    email: null,
    role: null,
    address: null,
    phoneNumber: null
  }
}

// Lot of switch cases here...
```

As for my action creator

```js
// Actions.js
// I'll create bunch of actions that dispatch to reducer
const updateName = (value) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_NAME,
    value: value
  }
}

const updateGender = (value) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_GENDER,
    value: value
  }
}

// and so on.., even for the error value

const updateError = (bodyType, value) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ERROR,
    bodyType: bodyType,
    value: value
  }
}

// Then, I'll export methods for my container component
export const onUpdateName = (value) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const nameError = validateName(value); // custom validation method
    dispatch(updateError(nameError));
    dispatch(updateName(value));
  }
}


// And more functions...

// And when the user hit SUBMIT
export const onSubmit = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const employeeInfo = getState().employeeReducer;
    if (employeeInfo.errors.name || employee.errors.gender) {
      // Checking every item in the object of errors, if error found, return
      return;
    }
    
    // Passed the validation, do something else...
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's quite messy (maybe ?) for a form validation component only, The `reducer` should remain *Pure* and the `container`only passes the data, thus leaving the `action creator` to handle all the logics and it doesn't look good in my case.

How do you keep your code clean if you ever ran into this kind of case ?

Answer (score 0):

Redux examples tend to be quite specific to provide clarity, however there is no reason why you can't use more general action creators.

For example, instead of having an action creator for each of the single value form fields, you can have just one like this:

```
const updateField = (field, value) => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_FIELD,
    field: field,
    value: value
  }
}
```

and later you can call the action creator like this

```
dispatch(updateField('gender', 'male'))
```

(also don't forget to update your reducer).

You can make similar universal action creators for errors and for adding/removing/clearing the multivalue form fields.

The one downside of doing this is that your action log will not be as readable - though it generally isn't a problem.